# "Click" - Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'

Tags: c#, delegates

I know there are alot of questions allready to this topic. But I can't really seem to understand this whole delegate stuff. I'm kinda at a point where I just want it to work and move on. Everytime when I look at delegates I think to myself, there has to be a way to make this much easier to understand and do, but I can't seem to find it.

I have a FlowLayoutPanel that will be filled with a bunch of Panels. each of those panels needs to have a OnClick (or Click?) method to be attached to it.

So I went ahead and wrote (inside of the creator of my personal panel class):

```
IntDrawForm form = FindForm() as IntDrawForm;
Click += form.PointPanelClick;
```

And I ended up with the error message `Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'` when tried to create one my panels.

Comment: It is quite ambiguous what you are asking about. What language are you writing in? What is the error message?

Comment: @gmoshkin: I think it's reasonable to assume it's C# in this case, and I believe the error message is as per the title, although that could certainly be clearer.

Comment: form can potentially be null. Try: `if (form != null) { Click += form.PointPanelClick; }`. By the way I am assuming you're coding in `C#`.

Comment: I am very sorry, yes this is c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will happen if `FindForm()` returns either `null`, or something that isn't an instance of `IntDrawForm`. There's nothing particularly specific to delegates here - you'd get a similar result if you tried this as your second line:

```
form.CallSomeMethod();
```

(In that case it would be a `NullReferenceException`.)

Given that the second line basically fails when `form` is `null`, you shouldn't use `as` here - use a cast instead. That way, the *first* line will fail if you don't have an `IntDrawForm`, and you'll get a more informative exception.

```
IntDrawForm form = (IntDrawForm) FindForm();
```

Now we can't tell *why* `FindForm()` has returned either `null` or a non-`IntDrawForm`, but that's a different matter.

Comment: ah yes of course form is null. ^^ the delegate stuff made me so furious that i totally overlooked this. I am writing this in the creator. so the panel isn't anywhere on the form yet. I simply need to send over my form handle as argument. thx alot. damn i feel stupid..